# Samba doesnt require password on xbmc but does on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, samba

I have samba setup on a fedora 13 machine, and I use it to share with my xbmc client in the family room.  When I set this up there no password or anything was required I merely entered in paths such as:

```
smb://<host>/<share> and all worked.
```

Now on my ubuntu 10.04 machine when I try to access the same hosts, for example through smbmount though I receive an error.

```
smbmount //media/Music ~/Music/  # media is in my /etc/hosts and resolves to 
                                 # correct IP address for the machine
```

I receive error: operation not permitted after pressing enter when it prompts for password.

Here is my entry from /etc/samba/smb.conf:

```
[global]

workgroup = WORKGROUP
server string = Samba Server Version %v


# log files split per-machine:
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
# maximum size of 50KB per log file, then rotate:
max log size = 50



security = user
passdb backend = tdbsam


;   security = domain
;   passdb backend = tdbsam
;   realm = MY_REALM

;   password server = <NT-Server-Name>

;   security = user
;   passdb backend = tdbsam

;   domain master = yes
;   domain logons = yes

;   logon script = %m.bat
;   logon script = %u.bat
;   logon path = \\%L\Profiles\%u
;   logon path =

;   add user script = /usr/sbin/useradd "%u" -n -g users
;   add group script = /usr/sbin/groupadd "%g"
;   add machine script = /usr/sbin/useradd -n -c "Workstation (%u)" -M -d /nohome -s     /bin/false "%u"
;   delete user script = /usr/sbin/userdel "%u"
;   delete user from group script = /usr/sbin/userdel "%u" "%g"
;       delete group script = /usr/sbin/groupdel "%g"

;   local master = no
    ;   os level = 33
    ;   preferred master = yes

;   wins support = yes
;   wins server = w.x.y.z
;   wins proxy = yes

;   dns proxy = yes


    load printers = yes
    cups options = raw

;   printcap name = /etc/printcap
    # obtain a list of printers automatically on UNIX System V systems:
;   printcap name = lpstat
;       printing = cups

;   map archive = no
;       map hidden = no
;   map read only = no
;   map system = no
;   store dos attributes = yes


#============================ Share Definitions ==============================

[homes]
comment = Home Directories
browseable = no
writable = yes
;   valid users = %S
;   valid users = MYDOMAIN\%S


# Un-comment the following and create the netlogon directory for Domain Logons:
;   [netlogon]
;   comment = Network Logon Service
;   path = /var/lib/samba/netlogon
;   guest ok = yes
;   writable = no
;   share modes = no

# Un-comment the following to provide a specific roving profile share.
# The default is to use the user's home directory:
;   [Profiles]
;   path = /var/lib/samba/profiles
;   browseable = no
;   guest ok = yes

# A publicly accessible directory that is read only, except for users in the
# "staff" group (which have write permissions):
;   [public]
;   comment = Public Stuff
;   path = /home/samba
;   public = yes
;   writable = yes
;   printable = no
;   write list = +staff

    [tv]
comment = TV
    path = /media/Isos/tv
    public = yes
    writable = yes
    printable = no
    write list = +media

    [music]
comment = Music
    path = /media/Storage/music/ 
    public = yes
    writable = yes
    printable = no
    write list = +media


    [pictures]
    comment = Pictures
    path = /media/Storage/pictures
    public = yes
    writable = yes
    printable = no
    write list = +media
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:  [HOW TO: Mounting smbfs Shares Permanently](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=255872&highlight=mounting+shares).

Comment: That document describes mounting them but uses username and password when doing smbmount.  What I do not understand is why a password is being required when in XBMC all I had to do was define a location such as smb://Music/ and no username or password was provided.

Comment: I don't know xbmc, but perhaps the way it was done there were implicit username/password, such as your login account.

Comment: Login on xbmc box is not a valid user on the ubuntu 10.04 running samba server.

Comment: This might make the difference. However, with permanently mounted shares you shouldn't care. You can try experimenting with a username/password combo identical to that of the xbmc box, although I don't think SMB supports this on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You may want to try the Guest options, particularly if only read-only access is required.</strike>

---

<strike>Then you have 2 choices</strike>

<strike>1. read only for guest (no authentication) but read/write if you authenticate when you map the share</strike>
 2. read/write for guest and then anybody can write to the share and change everything on it

---

Ah, does the user account you're running that mount command as have permission to mount directories?  I suspect not.  You may have to add it with the `user` option to your `/etc/fstab` file:

```
//media/Music /path/to/Music smbfs noauto,user,soft 0 0
```

---

That's my point - add it to fstab otherwise only root can mount the file system - that's almost certainly the source of your error.

Comment: Read-only is possible, but would prefer to have write abilities so I do not have to ssh to the box to make changes.

Comment: I am not using fstab, this is just using CLI to manually mount it. And I am mounting it in my mount directory ~/Music/ for example.

Answer (score 0):

Your samba is probably setup to map invalid users to the guest account.  Most likely, your xbmc uses `xbox` which is an invalid username on your samba server.  When you access from another linux box, the username probably is valid.  Check the `global` section of your `smb.conf`.

```
[global]
# This option controls how unsuccessful authentication attempts are mapped 
# to anonymous connections
   map to guest = bad user
```

You can add option to specify username, if you want to access it just as xbmc do.

`smbmount //media/Music ~/Music/ -o username=xbox`

Note that in your current configuration, guest are granted read-only access.  If you want to write, you would either:

1. allows guest to write (potentially
   dangerous)
2. add user with write access, and login as that user.  [Adding Users
   to Samba](http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/manual4/sambausers.html)

Comment: This seems promising! Question, when I try smbmount from CLI on my ubuntu 10.04 machine, without a username would this not map to a bad user also?

Comment: it would default to your username on that machine.  Do you have the same username on the samba server?  If so, then it'll check for valid password.

Comment: That did not work using username=xbmc.